# How to get the summation of values for subdocuments inside a document?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get a total of field values from a subdocument in another document in Firebase

database tree
[image]

I want to get all price values of all the ingredients inside syrup, so i can add it to the total price of the syrup

I have only seen the COUNT function, but it doesn't help me in this situation.